# quick Add Edit Delete api post in nodejs and jquery without page load

Tags: jquery, node.js, sqlite, crud

I am creating a CRUD app for my fan calcuation software on insert, update and delete queries in node js every time i needed to make reload process at the query success state. How to get the prompting and quick data entry without page loading. i add data and fetch back in select menu option list and table rows.
please refer my codes written and help/guide me to get a better solution to perform quick add edit delete process using jquery ajax and nodejs.

DB used sqlite3

code

Frond end

```
$('#addnewmodelform').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    var Series_ID = $('#Unit_Series option:selected').val();
    var Model_Name = $('#Unit_Series option:selected').text()+'-'+$('#Model_Name').val();
    if($('#Four_Pipe').attr('checked', true)){
        var Four_Pipe = 'TRUE';} else {var Four_Pipe = 'FALSE'}
    var Variant = $("input[name='Variant']:checked").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/addmodel",
        method: "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        data:  {
            Series_ID : Series_ID,
            Model_Name : Model_Name,
            Four_Pipe : Four_Pipe,
            Variant : Variant
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            location.reload();
        }
    })
})
```

backend

```
app.post('/addmodel', function  (req, res) {
if (req.body.Series_Pipe == 2){
    var twopipe = 'TRUE'
} else {var twopipe = 'FALSE'}
if (req.body.Series_Pipe == 4){
    var fourpipe = 'TRUE'
} else {var fourpipe = 'FALSE'}

    var query = 'INSERT INTO "Unit_Models"("Series_ID","Model_Name","m4Pipe","Dim_Image_file","Filter_Default","Coil_Default","Model_Number","Variant") VALUES ('
    query += "'" + req.body.Series_ID + "',"
    query += "'" + req.body.Model_Name + "',"
    query += "'" + req.body.Four_Pipe + "',"
    query += "'" + 'x'+ "',"
    query += "'" + '1'+ "',"
    query += "'" + '1'+ "',"
    query += "'" + req.body.Model_Name + "',"
    query += "'" + req.body.Variant + "'"
    query +=  ");"
    // query +='INSERT INTO "Unit_Models"("Series_ID") VALUES ('
    db.run(query, (err, results) =>{
        if(err) throw err;
        res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/')
    }) 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At your back end code you try to send the hole page to the jquery ajax function 
try to send from your code only the data you want to update and then you can update the ui page as you want

index.js

```
app.post('/addmodel', function (req, res) {
    if (req.body.Series_Pipe == 2) {
        var twopipe = 'TRUE'
    } else {
        var twopipe = 'FALSE'
    }
    if (req.body.Series_Pipe == 4) {
        var fourpipe = 'TRUE'
    } else {
        var fourpipe = 'FALSE'
    }

    var query = 'INSERT INTO "Unit_Models"("Series_ID","Model_Name","m4Pipe","Dim_Image_file","Filter_Default","Coil_Default","Model_Number","Variant") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'

    db.run(query, [req.body.Series_ID, req.body.Model_Name, req.body.Four_Pipe, 'x', '1', '1', req.body.Model_Name, req.body.Variant], (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message)
            res.send(err.message)
            return
        }

        console.log(`A row has been inserted with rowid ${this.lastID}`);
        // set your query 
        const sql = `SELECT  * FROM Unit_Models where ROWID=? `;

        db.all(sql, [this.lastID], (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(data)
            res.send(data);
        });
    })
    // close connection
    db.close((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
        console.log('Close the database connection.');
    });
});
```

jquery function

```
   $('#addnewmodelform').on('submit', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        var Series_ID = $('#Unit_Series option:selected').val();
        var Model_Name = $('#Unit_Series option:selected').text()+'-'+$('#Model_Name').val();
        if($('#Four_Pipe').attr('checked', true)){
            var Four_Pipe = 'TRUE';} else {var Four_Pipe = 'FALSE'}
        var Variant = $("input[name='Variant']:checked").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/addmodel",
            method: "POST",
            dataType : 'json',
            data:  {
                Series_ID : Series_ID,
                Model_Name : Model_Name,
                Four_Pipe : Four_Pipe,
                Variant : Variant
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                //here you can update your UI elements as you want 
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Thanks @petranb2. But i tried even the log(data) is not throwing the result data.
i tried with following code

`success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                alert(data)
                $Unit_Models.append($("<option> </option>").val(data.Model_ID).html(data.Model_Name));
                $('.bg-modal-add-model').fadeOut("slow")
                document.querySelector('.bg-modal-add-model').style.display = 'none';
            }`

Comment: I just add console.log(results) in back end code in order to see the format of the data set . I suppose that is an array that yout have to iterate them in your front end. You can update your post with the data set in order to help you iterate your data

Comment: its loging "undefined" after insert query, i dont what type the results output is

Comment: You have undefined because insert statement doesn't return any data in the callback function . If you want to get the new row from db you have to query again and send it to browser

Comment: Then how to get the last inserted data.. some thing like Select * from table where _rowid_ = last_insert_rowid()

Comment: Check the updated code with second query to fetch last inserted row